# How to place buttons in relative layout correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have relative layout where are some textviews added. They are displaying data from sqlite database.

I want to place two buttons that will be always placed below last result.

Please check images for more understanding.

Here is code for design:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="ID = "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#050505" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="UserID"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#050505" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Name = "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#050505" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewNAME"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewID"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#050505" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Nazov DVD = "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#050505" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDvd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="phone number"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#050505" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It's displaying now like this:

[image: screenshot-1]

And I want to display two buttons (edit and delete buttons) that will be displayed always below last result like this:

[image: screenshot-2]

I checked other articles but I really don't know how to apply it to my code.

Comment: where is the button in this xml?

Comment: This is the recycler item layout from my understanding. You need to post your full codes here to get the help you expect.

Comment: I think you need to take these Edit & Delete Button below Recycler view, so that as per the lenth of your list , after the number of items you can show button in bottom.

Comment: Instead of using these buttons you should use options menu. It's a better design procedure considering the possibilities of a very long list. Use options menu.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done really fast with [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) and [guidlines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html).

So you have said that you want your button to be below the last result - use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) to show your list of result, put a horizontal guideline and give it `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.your percent` so **you can decide** what will be the recyclerview height.

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:text="Edit"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Delete"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />
```

At the end it will look like this:

[image]

Now, remember that this is just an example and you can change it from the look of things, color, size, position on the screen and so on.